# Glassfish java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using webapp as dependency

Tags: java, glassfish, classpath

I'm trying to extend webapp functionality without redeploying webapp archive. App runs under Glassfish 3.

Basically, what I did is the following:

`webapp.war` contains some `part.jar` which is a part of webapplication. It contains some class `SomeClass`. Webapp allows some custom configuration where descendant of `SomeClass` may be loaded dynamically using `Class.forName`.

I derived `ExtensionClass` from `SomeClass` (`ExtensionClass extends SomeClass`), compiled it using `part.jar` and got some `extension.jar`.

I tried to put `extension.jar` into `domain/lib` and `domain/lib/ext`. But then app when loading `ExtensionClass` says `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SomeClass` (note that it says about parent class). It seems that classloader which loads library cannot find the base class, which is contained in the webapp.

**Goal**: I'd like to extend app using dependencies from it but without rebuilding.

**Question**: what can be done in this case?

**Edit**
If I just put my `extension.jar` into `applications/mywebapp/WEB-INF/libs` it obviously works, as if I'd put it into `webapp.war` itself. But it is very dirty, I want to solve it without doing this dirtiness and without touching `webapp.war`.

Comment: Have you seen [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/6nmndgmhp/index.html)? To load class from domain/lib you need to obtain `Common` classloader or some of his descendants.

Comment: I am not sure where should I obtain it

Comment: try current thead classloader `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`. Or i misunderstood your question? I thought that you just need to load and instantiate some class from domain/lib at runtime

Comment: Well, not just some class. Some class from domain/lib but that one extends the class from webapp itself.